# Exec format error: Try to compile .proto files into .py files with Raspberry Pi

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, proto

I`m a german studant. For the school I have to make a physics or chemistry project, I decided to install tensorflow on a raspberry pi to train a object detection modal. But there is an error I don´t understand. 'sh: 1: bin/protoc: Exec format error'

I tried all versions of protobuf from the source here:
[Source](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases)

I follow the instructions from the side:
[Instruction](https://gilberttanner.com/blog/installing-the-tensorflow-object-detection-api)

I use a raspberry pi 4 4gb ram. With Raspbain 10 (buster)

Answer (score 0):

`Exec format error` means that you're trying to run a binary that's not compatible with your system.
The Raspberry Pi 4 has an ARM Cortex-A72 CPU, and Raspbian is a 32-bit operating system, so you need a 32-bit ARM binary.
At first glance, none of the binaries that you can download from the GitHub page you linked to is a 32-bit ARM version, so you'll have to [compile it from source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1072684/740497).

Comment: Thank you! I could compile it from source.

Comment: But now I have the next error at installing the setup.py file:                                            
  File "/tmp/easy_install-m_kJas/matplotlib-3.2.1/setup.py", line 139
    raise IOError(f"Failed to download jquery-ui.  Please download "
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I'd like to point out that Raspbian (now Raspberry Pi OS) Lite 64-bit is currently in beta. For those interested here's the repo: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/images/